SPO Issues with Root Site Swap: Lost Navigation Menu and Access to Archived Classic Intranet Site
I swapped root sites from the admin center and I continuously receive the following when trying to navigate to the now-archived page that was our Intranet:

Out of curiosity, I attempted to re-establish the site as the root site just to see the prompts. As indicated, "This site can't be swapped. Only communication sites or modern team sites that have never had the classic publishing feature enabled can be swapped". While I believe I’ve captured all the essential information from the old intranet, I’d still prefer to have it archived and easily accessible, if needed.
Is there any way to retrieve the classic site, or is it beyond recovery?
